# Draw line and generate error when lines collide

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I'm drawing circle and want that when lines match together then generate error.I have done some coding and this code is able to draw lines on touch but problem is that when line match together its unable to generate error.So can anybody suggest me what i'm doing wrong.

**Code**

```
      public class DrawView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {
        private static final String TAG = "DrawView";

        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            DrawView.this.setOnTouchListener(DrawView.this);

            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            for (Point point : points) {
                canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);
                // canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, 5, 0, paint);
                // canvas.drawPaint(p);
                // Log.d(TAG, "Painting: "+point);
            }
        }

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            // if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            // return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = event.getX();
            point.y = event.getY();
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                if (point.equals(points.get(i))) {
                    System.out
                            .println("*****************************ERROR*******************************************");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Value of points" + points);
                    System.out
                            .println("***********************ELSE***********************************");
                }
            }
            points.add(point);
            invalidate();
            Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point);
            return true;
        }
    }

   class Point {
    float x, y;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Point))
            return false;
        Point p = (Point) o;
        return x == p.x && y == p.y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Don't all-caps your question, that will only serve to turn people away.

Comment: Define more clearly what you call "collide"

Comment: Read properly i have mentioned  all thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement equals()-method for your Point class. The default implementation probably won't compare your x & y attributes.

Comment: Thanks @jpa But can you tell me how.

Comment: @Dilip
`public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if ( !(o instanceof Point) ) return false;
  Point p = ( Point ) o;
  return x == p.x && y == p.y;
}`

Comment: @Dilip could you update the Point class's code? Maybe using floats is what gives you problems now if event.getX/Y() return non-integer coordinates

Comment: Actually i have to generate error as soon as line collide But this code doesn't work for that and its raise error before that

Comment: @Dilip No line still, so I don't quite understand the problem?